# Qt pinch Zoom in , Zoom out (pinchArea)

Tags: qt, qml, pinchzoom

```
enter code here
    PinchArea
    {
        MouseArea
        {
            id:dragArea
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: image
            scrollGestureEnabled: false
//            drag.maximumX: Screen.width
//            drag.maximumY: Screen.height

        }
        anchors.fill:image
        enabled: true
        pinch.target: image
        pinch.maximumScale: 4.0
        pinch.minimumScale: 1.0
        pinch.dragAxis: pinch.XAndYAxis
        pinch.maximumX: image.width
        pinch.maximumY: image.heighr
        onPinchStarted: {
            console.log("console ","pinchstarted")
        }

        onPinchUpdated: {

            console.log("console ","pinchUpdated")
        }
        onPinchFinished: {
            console.log("console ","pinchfinished")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to increase and decrease the scale by 0.1 when I pinch.
And when you take a log, too many onPinchUpdated are generated.
I want to log 1 step at a time when I pinch.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove `pinch.target: image` and instead manually set the scale of `image` based on rounding the `pinch.scale` value accessible in the onPinchStarted and onPinchUpdated handlers.

Something like:

```
PinchArea
    {
        MouseArea
        {
            id:dragArea
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: image
            scrollGestureEnabled: false
//            drag.maximumX: Screen.width
//            drag.maximumY: Screen.height

        }
        anchors.fill:image
        enabled: true
//        pinch.target: image
        pinch.maximumScale: 4.0
        pinch.minimumScale: 1.0
        pinch.dragAxis: pinch.XAndYAxis
        pinch.maximumX: image.width
        pinch.maximumY: image.heighr
        onPinchStarted: {
            console.log("console ","pinchstarted")
            image.scale = Math.round(pinch.scale / 10) * 10;
        }

        onPinchUpdated: {

            console.log("console ","pinchUpdated")
            image.scale = Math.round(pinch.scale / 10) * 10;
        }
        onPinchFinished: {
            console.log("console ","pinchfinished")
        }
    }
}
```